# getOpenFileNames dialog is not centered to the main window

Tags: qt, qt4, centering, fileopendialog, opendialog

Why the opened dialog is not centered to the main window?

```
void MainWindow::on_FileOpenAction_triggered()
{
    QStringList fileNames = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(
        this, 
        "Open Image",
        QApplication::applicationDirPath(), 
        "Images (*.jpg);;All Files (*.*)"
    );
}
```

The documentation says that is should work:

> This function creates a modal file dialog with the given parent widget.  If parent is not 0, the dialog will be shown centered over the parent widget.

I use QT 4.6.3 on Windows XP SP2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is either a bug in the Qt or an error in the documentation.
If you want a centered dialog, avoid the static functions and create dialog this way:

```
QFileDialog dialog(
    this, 
    "Open Image",
    QApplication::applicationDirPath(),
    "Images (*.jpg);;All Files (*.*)");
dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::ExistingFiles);
QStringList fileNames;
if (dialog.exec())
    fileNames = dialog.selectedFiles();
```

Note that this uses the Qt's file dialog and not the native file dialog.

Comment: I guess there is no option for native-centered solution. Any way thans for the post.

Answer (score 1):

Also in the [documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileNames) is the following:

> On Windows the dialog will spin a blocking modal event loop that will not dispatch any QTimers, and if parent is not 0 then it will position the dialog just below the parent's title bar.

Is this what is happening?  If not, I would guess that you've found a bug in Qt.

Comment: This is exactly what is happening. Is there a way to avoid it. I guess I should experiment constructing the dialog instead of using the hendy helper getOpenFileNames() routine.

Comment: @Gad D Lord: The only way I know of would be skipping the helper routine and positioning the dialog yourself.